# R using sapply for a function with multiple inputs

Tags: r, apply

I can't figure out how to use sapply for a function with multiple inputs.

If I have a vector and two matrices, I want to feed the vector and one row of the matrix into the function at a time:

```
A<-cbind(1000, 1000, 4000, 1333, 2333, 2333)
B<-cbind(rnorm(100), rnorm(100), rnorm(100), rnorm(100),rnorm(100), rnorm(100))
C<-cbind(rep(1, 100), rep(2, 100), rep(3, 100), rep(4, 100),rep(5, 100),rep(6, 100))

myFunc <- function(A, B, C) {
    X<-A * (B - C)
    #X[which(X<0)]=0
    return(sum(X))
}
```

so, I should receive a vector of 100 sums from this operation.

I guess I don't understand the structures well enough. I used `class()` on the variables and found that A is a matrix (1x6), B is a matrix (20,000x6), and C is a data frame (2x6 but I only send the first row). when I use mapply(myFunc, A,B,C) I actually get a result but it is a column of 120k rows, not 20k like I was expecting

Is `mapply` applying my function to every element in B?  Is there a way to make it operate only for each row?

Comment: Try `rowSums(sweep(B-C,2,A,\`*\`))` The `sum` function always returns a single result and the multiplication you were attempting isn't functional syntax in R.

Comment: my function is a bit more complicated than that, this was more of a simplified example.

Comment: The generalization of `sapply` to multiple arguments is `mapply`. However, it does not work row-by-row on matrices, only item by item on parallel lists. If you're working with matrices, it is almost certainly best to achieve your goals with matrix functions, like the basic algebra operators and `sweep`. Hard to get more specific without seeing your example.

Comment: You can duplicate your vector A with something like `replicate(100, A, simplify = F)` then use `Map/mapply` with any function. For example `Map("*", replicate(100, A, simplify = F), split(B-C, 1:100))`. Replace `"*"` with any function, add a `%>% lapply(sum)` to get the sum.

Comment: I guess I don't understand the structures well enough.  I used class() on the variables and found that A is a matrix (1x6), B is a matrix (20,000x6), and C is a data frame (2x6 but I only send the first row).  when I use mapply(myFunc, A,B,C) I actually get a result but it is a column of 120k rows, not 20k like I was expecting.

Comment: @user3390169 R data.frames are just lists. A matrix is just a 2-d array. A vector is a 1-d array. `*apply` operates over lists and arrays element wise. So columns/vectors are fed into `*apply` when  you pass it a list or data.frame. A scalar is passed when the input is vector, matrix, array.

Comment: @Vlo Thanks for the information.  How would you tackle my problem?  The function accepts 3 arguments of equal dimensions and I am trying to feed it one line of matrix B, all of matrix B and the second line of data frame C.  I ended up just using a for loop but it takes over two minutes to run and that is going to be a lot longer when I start trying to expand this to larger datasets and optimize the solution.

Comment: @user3390169 `*apply` family and for loop have similar speed assuming you don't store your results with something like results = c/rbind(results, current_results). A parallel version of for loop probably be the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing vector indexing with matrix column indexing, so use seq_along for the vector item and reference the column number in the matrices. I don;t think there is any R function that can read your mind for that goal.

```
A<-cbind(1000, 1000, 4000, 1333, 2333, 2333)
B<-cbind(rnorm(100), rnorm(100), rnorm(100), rnorm(100),rnorm(100), rnorm(100))
C<-cbind(rep(1, 100), rep(2, 100), rep(3, 100), rep(4, 100),rep(5, 100),rep(6, 100))

myFunc <- function(A, B, C) { X <- matrix(NA, nrow(B), ncol(B) )
   for (i in seq_along(A) ){
    X[, i] <-  A[i] * (B[, i] - C[,i])}
    X[ which(X<0)] = 0
   X   # if you do not want to collapse to single number, do NOT use `sum`
}
```